# Problems with bluetooth headset on fedora 17

Tags: audio, fedora, bluetooth

I tried bluetooth-wizard and bluedevil. It didn't work. I'm trying to use my bluetooth headset on my Dell Inspiron 1525, running Fedora 17, using a dongle. lsusb lists the dongle as follows:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
```

When I run hcitool scan. I get:

```
00:11:67:00:00:23   Sport Bluetooth
```

When I try to run blueman-manager, it outputs:

```
Loading configuration plugins
Using gconf config backend
_________
Load (/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:68)
['Services', 'PulseAudioProfile'] 
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on org.blueman.Applet:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/blueman-manager", line 301, in <module>
    Blueman()
  File "/usr/bin/blueman-manager", line 64, in __init__
    self.Plugins.Load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py", line 98, in Load
    __import__(self.module_path.__name__ + ".%s" % plugin, None, None, [])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/blueman/plugins/manager/PulseAudioProfile.py", line 30, in <module>
     if not "PulseAudio" in a.QueryPlugins():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 140, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 630, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus)
```

I'm becoming insane with this problem. Does anyone knows a way to solve it?